# Apache Spark Streaming: Median of windowed PairDStream by key

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to calculate the median value of a PairDStream for the values of each key.

I already tried the following, which is very unefficient:

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Iterable<Float>> groupedByKey = pairDstream.groupByKey();

JavaPairDStream<String, Float> medianPerPlug1h = groupedByKey.transformToPair(new Function<JavaPairRDD<String,Iterable<Float>>, JavaPairRDD<String,Float>>() {
        public JavaPairRDD<String, Float> call(JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Float>> v1) throws Exception {
            return v1.mapValues(new Function<Iterable<Float>, Float>() {
                public Float call(Iterable<Float> v1) throws Exception {

                    List<Float> buffer = new ArrayList<Float>();

                    long count = 0L;
                    Iterator<Float> iterator = v1.iterator();
                    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                        buffer.add(iterator.next());
                        count++;
                    }

                    float[] values = new float[(int)count];

                    for(int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) {
                        values[i] = buffer.get(i);
                    }

                    Arrays.sort(values);

                    float median;

                    int startIndex;

                    if(count % 2 == 0) {
                        startIndex = (int)(count / 2 - 1);

                        float a = values[startIndex];
                        float b = values[startIndex + 1];

                        median = (a + b) / 2.0f;
                    } else {
                        startIndex = (int)(count/2);

                        median = values[startIndex];
                    }

                    return median;
                }
            });
        }
}); 

medianPerPlug1h.print();
```

Can somebody help me with a more efficient transaction? I have about 1950 different keys, each can get to 3600 (1 data point per second, window of 1 hour) values, where to find the median of.

Thank you!

Comment: How often do you need the median to be calculated. Are you using a sliding window?

Comment: Actually I'm using a window of 1h (so the data is restricted and won't grow after this warm-up time) and a slide duration and batch interval of 2 seconds each. I could increase the batch and sliding interval, but I want to get a calculation as fast as possible. 

For me it would be more interesting to find a better transformation to profit more of Spark's parallel algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that I don't know why are you using Spark for that kind of task. It doesn't seem to be related to big data considering you got just few thousand of values. It may make things more complicated. But let's assume you're planning to scale up to bigger datasets.

I would try to use some more optimized algorithm for finding median than just sorting values. Sorting an array of values runs in **O(n * log n)** time.

You could think about using some linear-time median algorithm like [Median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians)

Comment: I'm just learning Spark and want to try out the abilities for calculating interesting values of a dataset in parallel. It should be a prototype for later adaptions for greater datasets. But this logic seems to be too expensive for huge data sets, as you mentioned above. 
I will have a look for the Median of Medians the next days, thank you for that information!

Answer (score 0):

1) avoid using groupbykey; reducebykey is more efficient than groupbykey.
2) reduceByKeyAndWindow(Function2,windowduration,slideDuration) can serve you better.

example:
JavaPairDStream merged=yourRDD.reduceByKeyAndWindow(new Function2() {
            public String call(String arg0, String arg1) throws Exception {
                return arg0+","+arg1;
            }
        }, Durations.seconds(windowDur), Durations.seconds(slideDur));

Assume output from this RDD will be like this :
(key,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
(key,1,2,3,4,5,6,7).
now for each key , you can parse this , you will have the count of values,
so : 1+2+3+4+5+6+7/count

Note: i used string just to concatenate.

I hope it helps :)